# Google Sheets: Action Based on Birthday

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to send myself either an email or copy the row to a new sheet when it's someone's birthday or hire date anniversary. Copying the line to a new sheet would allow me to use zapier to notify me of the update. Either would work. The sheet uses a form to collect data.

I've built a few scripts but nothing that had to do with dates. I'm just struggling with this one and have tried a few examples I could find with no luck.

[Here is this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xgztEnRJn8W9dJpMeg9X_jH6n73Qmpsz5BZe_s7iIyQ/edit?usp=sharing). It's view only so just let me know if you need more access.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to replicate your form responses Sheet in another Sheet (let's call it *Zapier Sheet*) automatically each time that a new form response is added. You can achieve that goal developing an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) code that runs at each form response. In that case you can use a code similar to this one:

```js
function so62400514() {
  var formSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '{FORM SHEET ID}').getSheets()[0];
  var zapierSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '{ZAPIER SHEET ID}').getSheets()[0];
  var formData = formSheet.getRange(1, 1, formSheet.getLastRow(), formSheet
    .getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var zapierData = zapierSheet.getRange(1, 1, zapierSheet.getLastRow(),
    formSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var recorded = false;

  for (var fr = 0; fr < formData.length; fr++) {
    for (var zr = 0; zr < zapierData.length; zr++) {
      if (formData[fr].toLocaleString() == zapierData[zr].toLocaleString()) {
        recorded = true;
      }
    }

    if (recorded == false) {
      zapierSheet.appendRow(formData[fr]);
    } else {
      recorded = false;
    }
  }
}
```

This code will first open both sheets (using [`SpreadsheetApp.openById()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) and [`Spreadsheet.getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)) to select the data with [`Sheet.getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) (setting boundaries with [`Sheet.getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) and [`Sheet.getLastColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)) and reading it using [`Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). After that operation the data will get iterated using the property [`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) as the perimeter. The iteration compares each row from the form Sheet to every row of the zapier sheet (to accomplish that, I first parsed the row as a string with [`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)). If the form row is found in the zapier sheet, the boolean `recorded` will flag to true. After every row on the zapier sheet gets compared to the form row, the code will write it down on the zapier sheet based on the boolean flag.

As explained in the previous paragraph, this code will take the form sheet rows not present in the zapier sheet; and paste them on the zapier sheet. I used this approach to prevent missing any row (as it could happen when simultaneous users answer the form all at once). To make this fire automatically you'll need to set up an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) with these settings:

[image: Installable trigger settings]

As an example, let's say that we have these form responses:

[image: Form data]

And our initial sample zapier sheet looks like this one below. Please, notice how several past rows are missing;

[image: Initial sample zapier sheet]

After running the script (as it will do automatically) this would be the result:

[image: Final sample zapier sheet]

I suggest running the script manually for an initial setup. If the timestamps diverge, please check if both spreadsheets share time zones. Don't hesitate to ask me further questions to clarify my answer.

Comment: This is really cool and I'll be using it for sure! The part that I really need is a trigger of some type based on the hire date or birthday. Is there a way to only copy a line over to the new sheet if someone's birthday is today or upcoming?

Comment: Hi there JesseNelson! You could use [`Range.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [`Range.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to copy rows to another Sheet. Since this operation is a completely new question, I recommend you to open it to receive appropriate help.